# Get user profile proerties on ShaprePoint online (office 365)

Tags: javascript, office-365, sharepoint-rest-api

I need code to get user profile properties by using JavaScript or JQuery

```
 var url = appweburl +"/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties";
 var requestHeaders = {
           "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
      };

 var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
     executor.executeAsync(
           {
                url: url,
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                method: "GET",
                headers: requestHeaders,
                success: function (data) {

                     var parsedData = JSON.parse(data.body);
                   alert(parsedData )

                },
                error: function (data) {
                     alert("failed");
                     console.log(data)
                }
           }
      );
```

the above code always throw error "Access denied,You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource". I am working on SharePoint office 365,any method using JavaScript or jquery is acceptable.

Comment: are you using sharepoint hosted app or provider hosted app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are working on SharePoint Hosted App.

So, your app must be permitted to access the user profile.

So follow this steps:

- Go to `AppManifest.xml`
- Add following code in AppManifest.xml

> ```
> <AppPermissionRequests>
>     <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl"/>
>   </AppPermissionRequests>
> ```

This solved my problem in past.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear your what is your **request** **Origin URL** and **Destination URL**. If you are requesting from http://a/ and destination is http://b/ then **CORS** check may be fiered and throwing "Access Denied". Else following code must work;

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://<site url>/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager
    /getmyproperties",
  type: "GET",
  headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});
```

Ref - [MSDN-PeopleManagerGetMyProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn790354.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#bk_PeopleManagerGetMyProperties)